# Java ambiguous type for method?

Tags: java, eclipse, ambiguous, ambiguous-call

**EDIT: This turned out not be a problem with the code at all, but with a bug in the Groovy Eclipse plugin (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-373)**

[Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) is giving me a weird error message about ambiguous types in a Java program and I really don't understand why. I have an interface that takes a generic parameter indicating what type of data it returns.

```
public interface InterfaceA<T> {
    T getData();
}
```

One of the implementations of it looks like this:

```
public class Impl<T extends AnotherClass> implements InterfaceA<Collection<T>> {
    public Collection<T> getData() {
       // get the data
    }
}
```

There is also a container for an InterfaceA

```
public class Container<T extends InterfaceA>
{
    private T a;

    public Container(T a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public T getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Doing this causes the "getData is ambiguous" error.

```
Container<Impl<AnotherClass>> c = new Container(new Impl<AnotherClass>());
Collection<AnotherClass> coll = c.getA().getData();
```

I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: Not seeing this problem in Eclipse 3.4.2 using JDK 1.6.0_10

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide us with details about `AnotherClass`. I just tried `java.util.Date` ( it's non-final ) in place of `AnotherClass` and it compiles fine in Eclipse.

Just a minor, you are missing `interface` in `InterfaceA` and `getData` should be public in `Impl`

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.5 with JDK 1.6.0_16, but I realized I didn't post broken code. I have updated the code with the actual problem.

Comment: Is this a compilation error or just eclipse highlighting the error? Does it actually compile?

Comment: It turned out it was an error with the groovy/eclipse plugin (I posted the details in my answer below) that was causing eclipse to report a compiler error when there was none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be a bug causing this from the groovy plugin. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-373. It is not a java problem at all. Thanks for the help and my apologies.

Comment: No apologies needed, i bet your question will be helpful to someone else (like me, for instance ;) )

Answer (score 2):

`Collection<T> getData()` defined in `Impl` needs to be made **public**.  If I do this the code compiles cleanly for me.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a copy/paste error. I realized the code I posted was not in error, but I have updated with the code that is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Your edited example works fine for me (JDK 1.5) with the exception, that you have to define the generic type on the constructor. Here is my complete working code:

```
public interface InterfaceA<T> {
    T getData();
}

public static class Impl<T extends Date> implements InterfaceA<Collection<T>> {
    public Collection<T> getData() {
        return null;
    }
}

public static class Container<T extends InterfaceA> {
    private T a;

    public Container(T a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public T getA() {
        return a;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Container<Impl<Date>> c = new Container<Impl<Date>>(new Impl<Date>());
    Collection<Date> coll = c.getA().getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here seems legitimate.  Perhaps Eclipse is showing an error it otherwise should not.

Go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings.  In the "Generic Types" section, ensure that Eclipse isn't reporting an error for any of the operations listed (unless you want it too).  I have all mine in that section set to "Warning".  I would then try refreshing the project and restarting Eclipse.

Edit:
After the updated post was made, I got a warning (not an error still) on the lines of usage, saying "Container is a raw type. References to generic type Container should be parameterized:".  This can be fixed by:

```
Container<Impl<Date>> c = new Container<Impl<Date>>(new Impl<Date>());
```

(In my example, I'm using java.util.Date as in place of 'AnotherClass').

Comment: It's not compiling cleanly for me... can't @Override an interface method implementation - it would have to be a superclass instead.

Comment: @Nate:  you're using 1.5.  Cuga is on 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit to reflect updated question]**

This shouldn't even compile as you are reducing the visibility of the method from public to package scope:

```
public class Impl<T extends AnotherClass> implements InterfaceA<Collection<T>> {
    Collection<T> getData() {
       // get the data
    }
}
```

And this **still compiles** for me (Eclispe 3.4, OS X, 1.5), so don't know what exactly is the issue:

package temp.tests;

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface InterfaceA <T> {

    T getData();

    public static final class AnotherClass {}

    public static final class Impl<T extends AnotherClass> 
             implements InterfaceA<Collection<T>>
   {
        public Collection<T> getData () {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class Container<T extends InterfaceA>
    {
        private T a;
        public Container(T a) { this.a = a; }
        public T getA() { return a; }
    }

    public static final class Test {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            Container<Impl<AnotherClass>> c = new Container(new Impl<AnotherClass>());
            Collection<AnotherClass> coll = c.getA().getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I posted an answer relating to the groovy/eclipse plugin. Turns out that was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have said, I am not seeing this problem on Eclipse 3.5.0 running on JDK 1.6.0.14 (when fixing the reduced visibility of the `getData()` method).

I suggest doing a clean build (Project/Clean in Eclipse). Also, the Eclipse and Java version you are running might help.

-- Flaviu Cipcigan

Comment: I have updated the code to correctly illustrate the problem. It still breaks in eclipse, but seems to work if I compile with just javac.